# Strange bug. Javascript, , Trying to run a loop, but getting a blank error in Chrome console

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loops, asynchronous

I'm running a loop on an array received from an obj `{message:Array(22)}` ajax call.  You can see the array has length = 22.  The first time through the loop, I console.log the lengths of the array, and my iterator.

```
console.log('got a message');
    var messages = resp_obj.message;
    console.log(messages);
    for(let x = 0 ; x < messages.length ; X++){
      console.log(messages.length);
      console.log(x);
      console.log(messages[x]);
    }
```

[image: notice the blank error message]

You can see the loop stops with a blank error.  Ive been stuck on this for a while.  the code prior to this is also giving me unpredictable results.

to make the ajax call, im listening to 3 select elements for onchange events, and waiting for all three to be set

```
<select>{...}</select>    
<select>{...}</select>    
<select>{...}</select>
//add event listener onchange
$.each($('select'), (i, v)=>{
$(v).addClass('not-set')
$(v).on('change', (e)=>{
  var tar = e.target
  var val = e.target.value
  var _found_data
  if(val==''){
    $(tar).addClass('not-set')
    $(tar).removeClass('is-set')
  }else{
    $(tar).removeClass('not-set')
    $(tar).addClass('is-set')
  }
  //each change event will also run this to check if all three are also set
  check_the_other_selects();

})
function check_the_other_selects(){
  var data_obj = {}
  $.each(select_items, (i, v)=>{
    var key = $(v).attr("name")
    var val = $(v).val()
    if(val=='') return
      data_obj[key]=val
    if(Object.keys(data_obj).length == 3){
      console.log('we got a full obj');
      console.log(data_obj);
      $.post('/output', data_obj, (resp)=>{
        console.log(resp);
        //run the loop function with this returned data that is causing the bug in the image posted about
      })
    }else{
      console.log('not full yet');
    }
  }) 
}
```

The most inconsistent part is what happens with the onchange events, and i've tried listening for input events also with similar results.  The handler for the onchange event will stop before running the `check_the_others` function, until i click another select, then it finished the first call to `check_the_others`.  The best outcome I have so far is this blank error, but im still stumped, any ideas?  Thank you.

Comment: `x != X`. Always check the console.

Comment: `X++` should be `x++`

Comment: in `for(let x = 0 ; x < messages.length ; X++){` you use capital `X` in `X++`

Comment: `X++` uppercase X, while the `let x` isset lowercase. `JavaScript` is case sensitive!

Comment: Change `let x = 0 ; x < messages.length ; X++` by `let x = 0 ; x < messages.length ; x++`

Comment: Not recommended to use `let x` too, It won't work in olders versions of `IE` and `Safari`. Use `var x` instead.

Comment: @Red - [works](https://caniuse.com/#feat=let) in IE 11 and Safari 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a capital X on this line causing an error and stopping the loop

```
for(let x = 0 ; x < messages.length ; x++)
```

Comment: Most likely because the issue is being a simple typo, and for that we don't answer, we vote/flag to close as such.

Comment: And I agree with that

Comment: Thanks for catching my error!  this is why you don't code at 2AM, that error message didn't help me at all